# I am trying to install icehrm on the host . I am getting "Primary script unknown" in nginx error.log

Tags: nginx, mysql, php-fpm

I am trying to install and configure [ICEhrm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/icehrm/files/) . However I was successfully able to unzip the file.

Here is my app/config.php file

```
    <?php 
ini_set('error_log', 'data/icehrm.log');

define('CLIENT_NAME', 'app');
define('APP_BASE_PATH', '/var/www/icehrm/');
define('CLIENT_BASE_PATH', '/var/www/icehrm/app/');
define('BASE_URL','http://hr.mycompany.com/icehrm/');
define('CLIENT_BASE_URL','http://hr.mycompany.com/icehrm/app/');

define('APP_DB', 'icehrm_db');
define('APP_USERNAME', 'icehrm_user');
define('APP_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('APP_HOST', 'localhost');
define('APP_CON_STR', 'mysqli://'.APP_USERNAME.':'.APP_PASSWORD.'@'.APP_HOST.'/'.APP_DB);

//file upload
define('FILE_TYPES', 'jpg,png,jpeg');
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE_KB', 10 * 1024);
```

And my nginx file is:

```
server {
        #see: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
    # see: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/icehrm;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://set-ip-address.xip.io
    server_name hr.mycompony.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But whenever I am going to hr.mycompany.com it redirecting to hr.mycompany.com/icehrm/app/login.php and the page is blank.

Please advise whats am I doing wrong.

Thanks,

Vady

~

Comment: You may have an extra `/icehrm` in your path. Both the `root` and the URI contain the term, so the physical location of `hr.mycompany.com/icehrm/app/login.php` is `/var/www/icehrm/icehrm/app/login.php`. Try using `root /var/www;` instead.

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thank you quick reply. I have only one /icehrm location and tried to change the root to /var/www but I am getting 403 forbidden error now on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your config as below. The problem is your base url and base path doesn't match according to nginx config

```
define('BASE_URL','http://hr.mycompany.com/');
define('CLIENT_BASE_URL','http://hr.mycompany.com/app/');
```